# Haskell Format String Output "(x, y),"

Tags: haskell

So I am trying to output a list of Points "(X,Y) \n" but I cant get it working.

Both values X and Y are Floats. I tried the module **text-format** but I cant make it work with Char and Float and the same time.

Anyone has an idea on how to make this work?

BEst regards

UPDATED:

```
format_pts_string cs = [
    format ("(" % a % ", " % b % ")")
    | c <- cs]
```

- This code is NOT working, Error -> [Print Of Error](http://prntscr.com/lm10p4)

Comment: `text-format` can deal with Char and Float at the same time. See [this example](https://github.com/bos/text-format/blob/master/benchmarks/Benchmarks.hs#L37). The `base` package also provides C like `printf` function (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Text-Printf.html).

Comment: you maybe not need `text-format` to print list of tuples. `show` and use `intersperse` to insert `\n` into list can output desired format for list of tuples. Anyway, Could you post what you have done so far? so that other users can learn what you want from the code.

Comment: @assembly.jc check update

Comment: @Hogeyama I am a newbie newbie in functional programming, could you please provide me with a simple sample, instead of that whole like? Thanks!

Comment: Which type of strings are you using? `String`? `Text`? Have you tried to simply `show` a pair of floats/double so that the pair is converted to a string? E.g. `show (3.2,1.5)` Do you need another output format than the one of `show`?

Comment: @assembly.jc how could I add then a ENTER "\n"? Btw thanks for the full explanation!!

Comment: Just append "\n" at the end of "result" `String`, the answer has updated to show how to do it, please see it.

Comment: @assembly.jc thanks for the quick answer! If you look at this image: 

http://prntscr.com/lm3479

I tried before but instead of printing the ENTER it prints the "\n" as a string

Comment: function `print` don't convert "\n" to new-line, use `putStr` or `putStrLn` instead.

Comment: @assembly.jc the problem is that I need to get a String as a output but putStrLn gives me a IO (), any thoughts on that?

Comment: comment is not suitable to discuss or chat, just ask an new question for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code of your question, I guess you want to convert a list of `Double` pair to a list of `String`, as said in comment, you may not need use `Data.Text.Format` package, since the basic function `show` can convert it to `String` properly as:

```
format_pts_string::[(Double, Double)]->[String]
format_pts_string cs = map (\c-> (show c) ++ "\n") cs
```

or use list comprehension:

```
format_pts_string::[(Double, Double)]->[String]
format_pts_string cs =  [show c ++ "\n" | c <- cs]
```

Furthermore, if need to control output format, you can use `++` to concatenate the `String`, here is an example:

```
format_pts_string::[(Double, Double)]->[String]
format_pts_string cs = map formatPair cs
    where formatPair (a, b) = "(" ++ (show a) ++ ", " ++ (show b) ++ ")" ++ "\n"
```

if you still love to use module **text-format**, you may need to enable `OverloadedStrings` language extension to convert `String` to `Format` type for call `format` function as:

```
{-# Language OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.Text.Lazy (unpack)
import Data.Text.Format (format)

format_pts_string::[(Double, Double)]->[String]
format_pts_string cs = [unpack $ format "({}, {})\n" (c::(Double, Double))| c <- cs]
```

or don't use `OverloadedStrings` language extension, use `formString` in `Data.String` instead, but it is verbose as:

```
...
import Data.String (fromString)
...
[unpack $ format (fromString "({}, {})\n") (c::(Double, Double))| c <- cs]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you have in mind?

```
main = let ps = [
                  (1.0,1.0), 
                  (2.0,2.0), 
                  (3.0,3.0), 
                  (4.0,4.0), 
                  (5.0,5.0), 
                  (6.0,6.0)
                ]
        in mapM print ps
```

output :

```
(1.0,1.0)
(2.0,2.0)
(3.0,3.0)
(4.0,4.0)
(5.0,5.0)
(6.0,6.0)
```

Comment: It is, but the situation gets more complex!

Point = (Float, Float)
Candidate = (Point, Point, [Point], Float)  - (Initial, Ending, [(Support)], Time)

So Basically I need to print something like (Imagine the shell):
(InitialX, initialY)
(Support1X, Support1Y),
....
(SupportnX, SupportnY)
(EndingX, EndingY),
Time: TIME